# asp.net SQL server error

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I am getting following error when I run my website on my laptop which i created on another computer

> The database 'C:\DOCUMENTS AND
>   SETTINGS\ASIF\DESKTOP\APP\WEBSITE\APP_DATA\DB.MDF'
>   cannot be opened because it is version
>   661. This server supports version 612 and earlier. A downgrade path is not
>   supported. Could not open new database
>   'C:\DOCUMENTS AND
>   SETTINGS\ASIF\DESKTOP\APP\WEBSITE\APP_DATA\DB.MDF'.
>   CREATE DATABASE is aborted. An attempt
>   to attach an auto-named database for
>   file C:\Documents and
>   Settings\asif\Desktop\App\Website\App_Data\DB.mdf
>   failed. A database with the same name
>   exists, or specified file cannot be
>   opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Please  suggest me solution to this.

Regards,
Asif Hameed

Answer (score 3):

Version 661 is SQL Server 2008 R2. You are trying to attach a database created with this version to an earlier version of the engine, which is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to use a SQL Server 2008 R2 database in SQL Server 2005?  They are not backwards compatible.

See http://forums.asp.net/p/1560835/3859344.aspx and http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlexpress/thread/2744a003-d61c-4d3d-93c2-af946e141e7e.

**Edit**

Also, if you have multiple SQL Server engines installed, make sure connection is pointing to the correct one.  It might be an instance name like `computername\instance` instead of just `computername`.

Comment: Do you have both SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2005 installed on the computer?  Make sure your connection string is pointing to the right instance.  You might have to specify `computer\instance` in your connection string.